# How to add mini_wishlist for django-oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am working for e-commerce sites with django-oscar.
I have problem with wishlist. I want to add mini_whislist on navbar. It's looks like oscar's basket_quick.

I did try this one, but its only working on wishlists section.

```
{% if wishlists %}
   {% for wishlist in wishlists %} 
       <span class="text-muted b">{{ wishlist.name }}</span>
       <span class="text-muted b">{{ wishlist.lines.count }}</span>
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static "images/topview.png" %}">
    <span class="p-2 text-muted b">EMPTY</span>
{% endif %}
```

How can I make it appear on every page?

Comment: Which template did you put this code inside? What is the full path for that template? Kindly edit the question and add these details.

Comment: I just using oscar's templates. However i customized with it bootstrap 4. So oscar's basket totaly works but they don't added wishlist_quick.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create  context processor in customer app...
**context_processors.py**

```
def wishlists(request):
    if not (request.user and request.user.is_authenticated):
        return {}
    return {
        'wishlists': request.user.wishlists.all()
    }
```

and put that into settings file

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    'customer.context_processors.wishlists',
)
```

then you can use wishlists anywhere

Comment: That's the very good idea! Thanks so much. I solved it like this with your help. Need some changes for my oscar versions[latest]. Create file in ..oscar/apps/wishlists/context_processors.py then in our settings.py file add this line in **TEMPLATES = > OPTIONS > context_processors :** ... 'oscar.apps.wishlists.context_processors.wishlists'

Comment: Sory i haven't seen this. When i logout i get this error: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'wishlists'
Can solve?

Comment: if not (user and user.is_authenticated):
        return {}
I have edited answer

Comment: Thank you so much again. I changed your code as follows;
`def wishlists(request):
 if not (request.user and request.user.is_authenticated):
  return {}
 else:
  return {'wishlists': request.user.wishlists.all()}`

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to put all the html you wrote for this feature into a HTML file and then use `{% include 'your_file.html' %}` in `layout.html`, it would not be a good idea to put in base.html since dashboard also extends the same base template.

Also, please note that you have to do the same in checkout/layout.html, because they have a separate layout for the checkout pages.

Comment: i did already, i think oscar's wishlist app set only in customer's profile but basket's app working all pages. thanks for your help.